# Load a Struts 2 action using jquery in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I'm trying to reload a target div from a javascript by using jquery to target the div and a struts action that loads the content.

Does anyone know how to do this?
The problem is how I use (javascript) jquery to do this.

BR, Tobias

Answer (score 7):

The simplest thing to do is use the jQuery `.load()` function.

```
$('#targetDivId').load('${your.struts.url}', function() {
  // stuff to do when the div has been reloaded
});
```

Now understand that you should make sure that the response from your action is a page that's not really a complete HTML page, because you can't stuff a complete HTML document inside a `<div>`.  If you have a complete document, and you only want a portion of it (say, a block contained within a `<div>` with id "usefullStuff"), you can do this:

```
$('#targetDivId').load('${your.struts.url} #usefullStuff', function() {
  // code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <sj:head/> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div> 
    <s:url id="ajaxTest" value="/AjaxTest.action"/> 

    <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxTest}" targets="div1"> 
      Update Content 
    </sj:a> 
  </body> 
</html>
```